# In Javascript/jQuery, is there a difference in rendering performance if I condense my code into "one-liners"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, interpreter

Is there a difference in performance (I am not asking about readability) if I condense my code into one line versus two?

For example:

`var slide = 'images/' + n + '.png';

   $('img').attr('src',slide);`

versus

`$('img').attr('src','images/' + n + '.png');`

Personally, I like fewer lines of code. Often, I am the only one reading my code, so communicating intent is not as important.

I am curious if the Javascript interpreter executes one of the above options faster (even though this is a classic micro-optimization example).

Comment: Even if you're the only one dealing with your code, it's easier to debug things if you separate them out, which can increase *your* performance in the long run. ;-)

Comment: Of course, using a variable (as in your example) makes lots of sense when you'll be reusing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micro-optimization doesn't half say it. :-)

The answer will depend a lot on the interpreter involved. I wouldn't be surprised if IE's interpreter had a *very very very very very very* (...continue saying "very" for a while...) *very slight, impossible to detect* difference. Chrome's V8, on the other hand, is certain not to.

In real terms, though? No, no difference at all.

Answer (score 5):

No difference in rendering performance, at all.

Comment: it certainly makes it harder to debug in some cases though.